# Migrating data from one MSSQL DB to another

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, database-migration

I was wondering if there is a safe/clean and efficient way to transfer data from one MSSQL DB to another on following terms:

- both DB's have exactly the same structure.

I need to be able to choose from which tables I'll export data, and then drop the data from new new table.

So it would look like this:

- drop data from beta DB
- insert data into DB from old DB

Does MSSQL has some sort of import/export wizard or some sort of tool which could help me with this ?

Comment: the better is to write your own script

Comment: If they are on the same server I suggest INSERT/SELECT statements

Comment: you can use an ETL tool like Talend.

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in wizard for data import/export in Sql Server Management Studio:

- right click on you DB
- click "Tasks"
- select "Import data..." or "Export data..."
- here you can select a source and a destination for you data transfer operations (for example you can chose SQL Server DBs as source and destination and transfer data from tables in the old DB to the same tables in the new DB), but I think that you'll need to write your own script to drop old data

Here is a screenshot that shows how to open this wizard:

[image]